# How to bold Chapter, Section name on the toc but not the dots and the numbers

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

Whenever i bold the text on the toc using `\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries}` the output will show like this:

> **2 Chapter Name ................................. 24**

> **2.1 Section Name ................................. 25**

But what i want is like this:

> **2 Chapter Name** ................................. 24

> **2.1 Section Name** ................................. 25

How to do this?

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ and which packages, if any, you load that affect the appearance of the Table of Contents. The reason I ask for this information is because the effect you describe and wish to get rid of is *not* the default under normal settings of the `tocloft` package (which defines `\cftsecfont`).

Comment: I'm using book-class. Sorry, turns out i only need to unbold the dots and the numbers on the chapter titles only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- To enable "dot leaders" for chapter-level entries in the ToC, you need issue the directive

  ```
  \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
  ```
- To get rid of the bolding of page numbers of chapter-level level entries, you need issue the directive

  ```
  \renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\mdseries}
  ```

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\mdseries}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Uno}
\chapter{Due}
\end{document}
```